# Receive error [Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint] on some db's, but not all

Tags: sql

Encountered an issue I've never seen before where I'm executing the same query on various databases in prod. Some DBs I receive [Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint] and other DBs it executes successfully. I'm curious what could trigger that They are supposedly the same db architecture, same ver of sql, same OS, same hardware, same everything. Only variance would be the data itself, but even then, the data is all the same character length.

Example:

[Server A:]
wc_name = Potato

[Server B:]
wc_name = Tomato

I understand how to get around this, just not sure why I have to get around it in the first place. I am not a DBA, nor do I have any RW access to these boxes, just RO.

Comment: "Only variance would be the data itself" - there's your problem. Bad data conversion

Comment: You would have to give us more information about the schemae we're dealing with before we could even attempt to answer this.

Comment: What causes it is values that can't be converted to an integer - either because they have non-numeric characters or overflow the range of `bigint`.  Unfortunately the error message doesn't tell you which record of even what value caused the error.